# Script to activate task list assign to email does not work anymore

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I have used successfully the below script to activate the defunct function in 2013 tasks lists Send email to assignee. It used to work perfectly and now I get an error in powershell saying that the action EnableAssignToEmail is not recognized.

Any clue on why this is happening and what should I do?

```
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://foo/web"
$list = $web.Lists.TryGetList("Tasks")

$list.EnableAssignToEmail = $true
$list.Update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you specified the right list. If the list cannot be found, your variable `$list` is going to be `null`. If you get an access denied on `TryGetList` this may also be a permission issue. If you are sure that your account has permissions to the list, run powershell as administrator, if you did not previously.

**Update:**

As you mentioned, `TryGetList` wants you to specify the list's title according to the [MSDN specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistcollection.trygetlist.aspx).

Comment: ok, finally it worked. I thought I had to place the real name of the list (what appears in the URL) and not what is the title of the list (what you can edit from list settings), is that the reason?

Comment: Yes, `TryGetList`asks for the title of the list as for MSDN specification https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistcollection.trygetlist.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Although EnableAssignToEmail has been removed from the UI it's still been working like expected when used the way you did. Also [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.enableassigntoemail.aspx) doesn't suggest any recent changes so most likely there is an issue with your list.